# How to filter a filed when it is Null or null character string?

Tags: python, django

How to filter a filed when it is Null or null character string?

I can only to check when it is null:

```
DataDictionary.objects.filter(parentlevel__isnull=True)
```

How about Null or null character string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the literal question, you may add empty strings into the filter query by using `Q` objects:

```
from django.db.models import Q
q = Q(parentlevel__isnull=True)
q |= Q(parentlevel='')
DataDictionary.objects.filter(q)
```

But, to answer the question behind the question, the docs recommend to avoid this awkward situation in the first place by initializing the field differently:

> Avoid using null on string-based fields such as `CharField` and `TextField`. If a string-based field has `null=True`, that means it has two possible values for "no data": NULL, and the empty string. In most cases, it’s redundant to have two possible values for "no data;" the Django convention is to use the empty string, not NULL.

So, I recommend you make this change on the `DataDictionary` model and add the corresponding data migration to convert nulls into empty strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Q`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/queries/#django.db.models.Q) to combination query like this:

```
DataDictionary.objects.filter(Q(parentlevel__isnull=True) | Q(parentlevel=''))
```